# Ways to apply bleed effect?

Tags: the-division-2

I've been thinking of ways to activate the Sadist talent, which causes weapons to deal more damage to bleeding targets.

How can you apply the bleed status effect to enemies?

Answer (score 6):

Applies 'bleed' to enemies:

- knee cap leg shots
- Demolitionist grenades (they also have a larger radius, but deal less damage)
- Explosions from red canisters/tanks/...
- Explosive ammunition
- Sadist weapon talent
- Stinger Hive skill
- Trauma chest armor talent (body shots, cooldown 30s)
- Eclipse Protocol gearset (can spread status effects)
- Ongoing Directive gearset (grants bullets that turn bleeding)
- Ridgeway's Pride chest piece (applies bleed to any enemy hit within 15)